# NFS drupal implementation

Tags: php, drupal, nfs, multiserver

I found out NFS is the best way for Multi Server setup in Drupal File sharing

Can someone tell me how this works.

I have two Servers with Drupal Files connected to a common db in third Server

I have one more Server for files how shall I link this too both Drupal Servers using NFS and how NFS works?

when a user uploads the file from first drupal server does it make a copy in Shared Server or makes a

symbolic(soft) link in both drupal servers and adds the file in shared server?

Can someone please tell me and pass me a link to implement NFS for my MultiServer Drupal Setup.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/set-up-easy-file-sharing-with-nfs-on-linux/1939

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume Server-A (ip: a.a.a.a) is the server where you are going to save the files,  Server-B(ip: b.b.b.b) and Server-C (ip: c.c.c.c) will have drupal. In Server-A you may be storing the files in /store folder. This is to be mounted to folder /mnt/store in Server-B and Server-c.

For this you need to install nfs-kernal-server in Server-A and nfs-common and portmap on all three servers. NFS relies upon Remote Procedure Call(RPC) and portmap service is required to map RPC requests to the correct services.

In Server-A do these configurations:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server portmap nfs-common
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/nfstest
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/nfstest
sudo mount  --bind /store /mnt/nfstest
```

`sudo vi /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` in this file set  `NEED_SVCGSSD=no`

`sudo vi /etc/default/nfs-common` in this file set: `NEED_IDMAPD=yes` and `NEED_GSSD=no`

`sudo vi /etc/idmapd.conf` in this file under `[Mapping]` set `Nobody-User = nobody` and `Nobody-Group = nogroup`

`sudo vi /etc/hosts.deny` add this: `portmap mountd nfsd statd lockd rquotad : ALL`

`sudo vi /etc/hosts.allow` add this: `portmap mountd nfsd statd lockd rquotad :  b.b.b.b, c.c.c.c` {ipaddresses}

`sudo vi /etc/exports` add this: `/mnt/nfstest b.b.b.b(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)` and  `/mnt/nfstest c.c.c.c(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)`

```
sudo exportfs -ra
sudo /etc/init.d/portmap restart
sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
```

In Server-B and Server-C do this

```
sudo apt-get install portmap nfs-common
sudo vi /etc/hosts.deny SET: `portmap : ALL`
```

`sudo vi /etc/hosts.allow` SET: `portmap : a.a.a.a` {Server-A's ipaddress}

`sudo vi /etc/default/nfs-common` SET: `NEED_IDMAPD=yes` and `NEED_GSSD=no`

`sudo vi /etc/idmapd.conf` under `[Mapping]` add `Nobody-User = nobody` and `Nobody-Group = nogroup`

```
modprobe nfs
mkdir /mnt/store
sudo mount -t nfs4 a.a.a.a:/ /mnt/store
```